# QThreaded C++ daemon does not shutdown properly

Tags: c++, qt, fork, qthread

I have written a Qt5/C++ program which forks and runs in the background, and stops in response to a signal and shuts down normally.  All sounds great, but when I "ps ax | grep myprog" I see a bunch of my programs still running; eg:

```
29244 ?        Ss   149:47 /usr/local/myprog/myprog -q
30913 ?        Ss     8:37 /usr/local/myprog/myprog -q
32484 ?        Ss     0:11 /usr/local/myprog/myprog -q
```

If I run the program in the foreground then the process does NOT hang around on the process list - it dies off as expected.  This only happens when in the background.  Why?

---

Update: I found that my program is in futex_wait_queue_me state (queue_me and wait for wakeup, timeout, or signal).  I do have 3 seperate threads - and that may be related.  So I attached a debugger to one of the waiting processes and found this:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000372460b575 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007f8990fb454b in QWaitCondition::wait(QMutex*, unsigned long) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.1.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#2  0x00007f8990fb3b3e in QThread::wait(unsigned long) () from /opt/Qt/5.1.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#3  0x00007f8990fb0402 in QThreadPoolPrivate::reset() () from /opt/Qt/5.1.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#4  0x00007f8990fb0561 in QThreadPool::waitForDone(int) () from /opt/Qt/5.1.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#5  0x00007f89911a4261 in QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) ()
   from /opt/Qt/5.1.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#6  0x00007f89911a4d5f in QObject::destroyed(QObject*) () from /opt/Qt/5.1.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#7  0x00007f89911aa3ee in QObject::~QObject() () from /opt/Qt/5.1.1/gcc_64/lib/libQt5Core.so.5
#8  0x0000000000409d8b in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffba44c8f8) at ../../src/main.cpp:27
(gdb)
```

---

Update:

I commented out my 2 threads, so only the main thread runs now, and the problem is the same.

Is there a special way to cause a background process to exit?  Why won't the main thread shutdown?

---

Update:
Solved - Qt does not like Fork.  (See another StackExchane questoin).  I had to move my fork to the highest level (before Qt does anything), and then Qt doesn't hang on exit.

Comment: Please give your code details.

Comment: These are not zombies. Zombies would have a `Z` where you have an `Ss`. Attach a debugger to them and see what they're waiting for.

Comment: You need to show your source code.

Answer (score 2):

- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html#PROCESS_STATE%20CODES

> **PROCESS STATE CODES**
>
> Here are the different values that the **s**, **stat** and **state** output specifiers (header "STAT" or "S") will display to describe the state of a process:
>
> ```
>   D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
>   R    running or runnable (on run queue)
>   S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
>   T    stopped, either by a job control signal or because it is being traced.
>   W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
>   X    dead (should never be seen)
>   Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent.
> ```
>
> For BSD formats and when the stat keyword is used, additional characters may be displayed:
>
> ```
>   <    high-priority (not nice to other users)
>   N    low-priority (nice to other users)
>   L    has pages locked into memory (for real-time and custom IO)
>   s    is a session leader
>   l    is multi-threaded (using CLONE_THREAD, like NPTL pthreads do)
>   +    is in the foreground process group.
> ```

So your processes are all in "S: interruptible sleep."  That is, they are all waiting for blocking syscalls.

You might have better hints on what your programs are waiting for from this command:

```
$ ps -o pid,stat,wchan `pidof zsh`
  PID STAT WCHAN
 4490 Ss   rt_sigsuspend
 4814 Ss   rt_sigsuspend
 4861 Ss   rt_sigsuspend
 4894 Ss+  n_tty_read
 5744 Ss+  n_tty_read
...
```

"wchan (waiting channel)" shows a kernel function (=~ syscall) which is blocking.

See also

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/19442/what-is-the-waiting-channel-of-a-process

Comment: Ok - i tried this and I see that myprog is listed as "futex_wait_queue_me".  having trouble finding what that means.  I have 3 threads in my app - does that mean a thread is still running?  (I thought I stopped them all)